# How Fourier transform and scaled Fourier transform are related?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $d>1$ and $A$  be a diagonal  matrix with real entries  $\{ a_1, ...., a_d\}$  and $\det A \neq 0.$
 For  $m=(m_1,..., m_d) \in \mathbb R^d, Am= (m_1a_1,..., m_da_d)$   as usual. 
 The Fourier transform of  $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ is given by
 $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi} dx$

> What relation one can expect between $\hat{f}(Am)$ and $\hat{f}(m)$?

Side note: In one dimension, if $h(x)=f(ax)$ $(x\in \mathbb R, 0\neq a \in \mathbb R),$ then  $\hat{h}(\xi)= \frac{1}{|a|} \hat{f}(\frac{\xi}{a})$

Comment: In general there is not much to say to the question, but if you are asking for the transform of $f(Ax)$ then write out the integral and do the change of variable and you''ll get $\frac{1}{|a_1|\cdots|a_n|}\hat f(A^{-1}\xi)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is an invertible matrix and $g(x)=f(Ax)$, then $\hat g(\xi)=\det(A)^{-1}\hat f(A^{-T}\xi)$.
Here $A^{-T}$ is the transpose of the inverse (or the inverse of the transpose).
To see this, simply write out the definition of $\hat g(\xi)$ and change the variable of integration from $x$ to $y=Ax$.

In your specific case the determinant is the product of all the diagonal entries and $A^{-T}=A^{-1}$.